# problema con javascript en select

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un campo seleccionar que al momento de seleccionar me devuelve los datos de los usuarios normalmente pero me deja agregar una opcion nula en el campo personas...

```
<tr id="campo-select">
        <td>    
            <strong>Personas:</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php $consulta_listar_usuario = $usuario->listUserpordepartamentodos($conexion, $id_departamento ); ?>
            <span id="error-persona">
                <select class="browser-default" name="persona0" id="persona0" required>
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONE A QUIEN NOTIFICAR</option>
                    <?php while($resultado_listar_usuario = $consulta_listar_usuario->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['idUsuario'];?>"><?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['personaNombre'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['apellido'];?>   <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['email'];?> <?php echo $resultado_listar_usuario['nombreDepartamento'];?></option>





                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                 </select>
            </span>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn" id="suma_persona" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn" id="borra_persona" ><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="cantidad_persona" id="cantidad_persona">
        </td>

    </tr>
```

cuando presiono el boton

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn" id="suma_persona" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
```

me agrega el campo SELECCIONE A QUIEN NOTIFICAR en el input tantas veces como le de y no quiero que se comporte asi , alguna sugerencia?

editado , aqui esta mi js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#suma_persona" ).on('click',function() {

            $("#error-persona").append($("#persona0").clone().attr('id', 'persona'+(++c) ));
            $("#persona"+c).attr('name', 'persona'+c);
            $("#persona"+c).val(0);
            $("#cantidad_persona").val(c);
        });

        $( "#borra_persona" ).on('click',function() {

          if(c>0){

            $( "#persona"+c ).remove();
            c--;
          }
        });

        $("#campo-asunto").hide(); 
        $("#campo-select").hide();

        $( "#informar" ).click(function() {

          if($("#informar").is(':checked')){

            $("#campo-asunto").show(); 
            $("#campo-select").show();
          }
          else{

            $("#campo-asunto").hide(); 
            $("#campo-select").hide();
          }
        });

      });
```

Comment: y tienes el código que tomas esos valores , el javascript que no lo veo. Ponlo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: si claro sebastian . ya lo coloco .

Comment: tambien me estoy dando cuenta que no me respeta el hecho que sea 100 veces la misma persona me deja seleccionarlo y continuar . 
voy empezando , les agradezco su ayuda .

Comment: El append debería ser sobre $("#persona0")..., ya que aquí es donde vas a agregar los options.